# Deny HTTP direct access to PDF, but allow after logging into User Management System

Tags: php, .htaccess, password-protection, login-control

I have found many people asking similar questions with a lot of answers, but nothing that has helped me.

Is there a way to have files (pdf, images, etc) in a password protected folder that users can view when logged into a User Manager System, but not be able to access when logged out? I purchased a PHP User Management System on CodeCanyon which has features to restrict access to pages, but not files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what did you try to do?

Comment: Potentially could use `.htaccess` to redirect `/files/document.pdf` to `/scripts/pdf_viewer.php?file=document.pdf` and verify a valid user before serving up the PDF with `file_get_contents()` and setting your headers to `Content-type: application/pdf`.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I will research this and see what I can figure out. Once I find a working solution, I will post it.

Comment: msangel, currently I'm using http://username:password@www.domain.com/training/theprocess.pdf which doesn't work in IE.

Comment: This seems to be an area that is beyond my skill set right now so I will just convert the PDFs to pages and just serve the HTML.